# Is it light or lights?

Tags: expressions, idioms, nouns

"He turned off the lights in the kitchen."

I never see the singular "light" in these kinds of sentences even when referring to only one light bulb. Does this mean that "lights" can mean either singular or plural?

Comment: If the speaker and the audience are both familiar with the fact that there's only one light bulb in the room, the speaker would probably say "the light" in normal discourse.

Answer (score 2):

"Lights" in this context usually suggests "all the light bulbs in the room".

"Light" can also mean that, if there's only one light bulb. But it can also mean the sum total of all the light that is illuminating the room; if you turn off all the lights, you've also turned off the light.